# Sql query. Syntax error, unexpected '"'

Tags: php, sql

This is my query:

```
$q="INSERT INTO users2 (id_fb,name, firstname ) VALUES($_SESSION["userprofile"]["id"],$_SESSION["userprofile"]["name"],$_SESSION["userprofile"]["first_name"])";
```

I have this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

How to do it correctly?

Comment: SQL Injection - read about it here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Unless the session is hijacked, it's not really likely in this case.

Comment: @njk How about accidental SQL injection (what if my username is "O'Brien")?

Comment: @njk The parsing of data into a session is unlikely to be of the same required level of security to prevent SQL injection. There are too many chances something can go wrong somewhere. It makes sense to protect the database at the source - not out in some random function at login

Comment: You forgot to read the PHP manual page on string interpolation. Or your PHP book.

Answer (score 3):

you need to quote:

```
$q="INSERT INTO users2 (id_fb,name, firstname ) 
  VALUES('".(int)$_SESSION["userprofile"]["id"]."',
         '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION["userprofile"]["name"])."',
         '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION["userprofile"]["first_name"])."')";
```

But better use prepared statements tho...

```
   $q = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `users2` SET 
                   `id_fb` = ?, `name` = ?, `firstname` = ?");
   $q->execute( array( (int)$_SESSION["userprofile"]["id"], 
            $_SESSION["userprofile"]["name"], 
            $_SESSION["userprofile"]["first_name"]));
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and an appropriate alternative.

Comment: -1 for SQL injection in your first solution.

Comment: My first example is not the solution, just how he could fix his problem for now. And how would the user get access to the variables in $_SESSION, I assume $_SESSION is set up in a safe way. Downvoting my working answer with a good extra example on how he should do it feels harsh to me.

Comment: @John I don't care how the user got access to `$_SESSION`, and if you don't write code that's vulnerable to SQL injection, the answer doesn't matter. Just don't do it.

Comment: @mel I changed my answer (added the native escape function), happy now?

Comment: @John I think someone is just really bitter.

Comment: @melpomene John is now using `mysqli_`. Anything else you wish to be bitter about?

Comment: ^^ He is really bitter. Of course we know it should not be used anymore, but it solves his problem in the best way possible you could with mysql right?

Comment: @John No, `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes two arguments.

Comment: @melpomene Actually, if you [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) the second argument is **optional**.

Comment: @njk Well, I use PDO to be honest, in my opinion a little easier than mysqli. at melpomene Thanks for being critical, always good to have things in perspective :-).

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT USE** mysql_*, they have been deprecated. Also, You are prone to SQL injection.

Now to your problem. You are using double quotes to build a string. When the statement reaches your first `$_SESSION["` the double quote closes out your string construction. You have to use single quotes in your sessions. As such: `$_SESSION['id']`

Further clarification:

`$var = "This is a "statement"";` Will not produce the output `This is a "statement"` since the string was closed at the double quote before statement. You must escape the inside double quotes to show them (`\"`). Also, `$var = "This is a 'statement'";` will output `This is a 'statement'` since the single quotes do not close a statement started with double quotes and vis-versa.

In this question, the use of double quotes to start the string allows the execution of variables but array items must use single quotes when using their indexes as such: `$_SESSION['name']` and not `$_SESSION["name"]`.

For future assistance, do some research on the errors PHP is giving you, they tend to tell you or lead you to your issue. Also, read up on the basics of PHP.

Comment: I don't think `"` vs `'` is the problem here.

Comment: It is his problem, he opens the string with `"` and does not escape the double quotes in the statement

Comment: Not quoting can cause unexpected problems (variables not being parsed etc), so it is bad practice to not do it. Just quote the whole variable, then it does not matter if you use " or '

Comment: @melpomene If the array is not inline, [it does not matter](http://codepad.org/4JOEiNCm).

Comment: @njk I don't understand what that is supposed to demonstrate (or what an inline array is).

Comment: @melpomene Double quotes are perfectly acceptable to call the value of an array when [it is not inline](http://codepad.org/lvaf8Ik7). `echo $array["1"]["2"];` vs `echo "color $array["1"]["2"]";`

Comment: @njk What do you mean by "inline"?

Comment: @melpomene I just gave you an example.

Comment: @njk Yes, but that doesn't tell me what you mean.

Comment: *"array items must use single quotes when using their indexes"* this is just simply incorrect. [See this example](http://codepad.org/lvaf8Ik7).

Comment: @njk I have no idea who or what you're quoting here.

Comment: @melpomene Then you have not read UnholyRanger's answer apparently.

Comment: @njk yes arrays may use double quotes. the statement was going for when they are evaluating the array in a string started with a double quote, that when not ending the quote, the single quote must be used.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
 $q="INSERT INTO users2 (id_fb,name, firstname ) VALUES($_SESSION['userprofile']   ['id'],$_SESSION['userprofile']['name'],$_SESSION['userprofile']['first_name'])";
```

Comment: Mysqli is ok, i don't accept your -1!

Comment: Have you heard about SQL injection?